# Verify Email (check if email inbox exists) using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, automation, smtp

I am looking for a way to programmatically check if an email is a valid email using node js. After doing some research I ended up on this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2J4u2NzarI&t=1617s&ab_channel=ToastyBits).

now after following the video, I have this code:

```
const { randomBytes } = require('crypto');
const promises = require('dns').promises;
const net = require('net');


const resolveMXRecords = async (domain) => {
    console.log('resolving mx records for domain...', domain)
    try {
        return await promises.resolveMx(domain)
    } catch (error) {
        return []
    }
}

const verifyEmailFormat = (email) => {
    const regex = new RegExp({ pattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$', flags: 'i' });
    return regex.test(email);
};

const SMTPStages = {
    CHECK_CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED: 'CHECK_CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED',
    SEND_EHLO: 'SEND_EHLO',
    SEND_MAIL_FROM: 'SEND_MAIL_FROM',
    SEND_RECIPIENT_TO: 'SEND_RECIPIENT_TO',
    SEND_QUIT: 'SEND_QUIT'
}

const testInboxOnSMTPServer = async (inboxAddress, smtpAddress) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const result = {
            connection_established: false,
            account_exists: false
        }

        const socket = net.createConnection(25, smtpAddress)
        const stages = {
            [SMTPStages.CHECK_CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED]: {
                expected_reply_code: '220'
            },
            [SMTPStages.SEND_EHLO]: {
                command: `EHLO mail.example.org\r\n`,
                expected_reply_code: '250'
            },
            [SMTPStages.SEND_MAIL_FROM]: {
                command: `MAIL FROM:<name@example.org>\r\n`,
                expected_reply_code: '250'
            },
            [SMTPStages.SEND_RECIPIENT_TO]: {
                command: `RCPT TO:<${inboxAddress}>\r\n`,
                expected_reply_code: '250'
            },
            [SMTPStages.SEND_QUIT]: {
                command: `QUIT\r\n`,
                expected_reply_code: '221'
            }
        }

        let response = ""
        let currentStageName = SMTPStages.CHECK_CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED

        socket.on("data", (data) => {
            const reply = data.toString()
            response += reply

            // console.log('<-- ' + reply)
            const currentStage = stages[currentStageName]

            switch (currentStageName) {
                case SMTPStages.CHECK_CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED: {
                    if (!reply.startsWith(currentStage.expected_reply_code)) {
                        socket.end()
                        break
                    }

                    result.connection_established = true
                    currentStageName = SMTPStages.SEND_EHLO
                    const command = stages[currentStageName].command
                    socket.write(command, () => {
                        console.log('--> ' + command)
                    })

                    break
                }

                case SMTPStages.SEND_EHLO: {
                    if (!reply.startsWith(currentStage.expected_reply_code)) {
                        socket.end()
                        break
                    }

                    currentStageName = SMTPStages.SEND_MAIL_FROM
                    const command = stages[currentStageName].command
                    socket.write(command, () => {
                        console.log('--> ' + command)
                    })

                    break
                }

                case SMTPStages.SEND_MAIL_FROM: {
                    if (!reply.startsWith(currentStage.expected_reply_code)) {
                        socket.end()
                        break
                    }

                    currentStageName = SMTPStages.SEND_RECIPIENT_TO
                    const command = stages[currentStageName].command
                    socket.write(command, () => {
                        console.log('--> ' + command)
                    })

                    break
                }

                case SMTPStages.SEND_RECIPIENT_TO: {
                    if (!reply.startsWith(currentStage.expected_reply_code)) {
                        socket.end()
                        break
                    }

                    result.account_exists = true
                    currentStageName = SMTPStages.SEND_QUIT
                    const command = stages[currentStageName].command
                    socket.write(command, () => {
                        console.log('--> ' + command)
                    })

                    break
                }
            }
        })

        socket.on("connect", () => {
            console.log("Connected to SMTP " + smtpAddress)
            console.log('Local address: ' + socket.localAddress + ' Local port: ' + socket.localPort);
            console.log('Remote address: ' + socket.remoteAddress + ' Remote port: ' + socket.remotePort);
        })

        socket.on("error", (error) => {
            // clearInterval(timeoutTimer)
            reject(error)
        })

        socket.on("close", () => {
            // clearInterval(timeoutTimer)
            resolve(result)
        })
    })
}

const validateEmail = async (email) => {
    const emailFormatValid = verifyEmailFormat(email)
    if (!emailFormatValid) {
        return 'invalid email format'
    }

    const [, domain] = email.split('@')
    const mxRecords = await resolveMXRecords(domain)
    const sortedMxRecords = mxRecords.sort((a, b) => a.priority - b.priority)
    console.log('sortedMxRecords', sortedMxRecords)

    let smtpResult = { connection_established: false, account_exists: false }
    let hostIndex = 0

    while (hostIndex < sortedMxRecords.length) {
        try {
            console.log('testing inbox on smtp server', sortedMxRecords[hostIndex].exchange)
            smtpResult = await testInboxOnSMTPServer(email, sortedMxRecords[hostIndex].exchange)
            if (!smtpResult.connection_established) {
                console.log('connection not established')
                hostIndex++
            }
            else {
                break
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('error while testing inbox on smtp server', error)
            hostIndex++
        }
    }
    let usesCatchAll = false
    try {
        const testCatchEmail = `${randomBytes(20).toString('hex')}@${domain}`
        const testCatchAll = await testInboxOnSMTPServer(testCatchEmail, sortedMxRecords[hostIndex].exchange)
        usesCatchAll = testCatchAll.account_exists
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

    return {
        email_format_is_valid: emailFormatValid,
        usesCatchAll: usesCatchAll,
        ...smtpResult
    }

}

async function main() {
    let email = 'abc@liqueous.com'
    const result = await validateEmail(email)
    console.log('result', result)
}
main()
```

This code works for the most part. It gives somewhat accurate results when I try to run it. But I am facing some problems the first one being that when I try to run the same code on a remote Linux server it constantly gives me a connection error. Secondly, I want to check a very large list of emails (approx 4 million). How can I achieve that without getting blocked or banned by the server and how can I handle connection problems for some emails? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let' see another variant to do that, I think it is more easy way to validate email.

1. First, you have to install Deep Email Validator by using this command:
   `npm install deep-email-validator`
2. Then you have to create the logic for performing the verification. It will look like this:

   ```
   const router = express.Router();
   const emailValidator = require('deep-email-validator');
   async function isEmailValid(email) {
   return emailValidator.validate(email)
   }
   ```
3. When the asynchronous function is run, you will get this response:

   ```
     valid: false,
     validators: {
       regex: { valid: true },
       typo: { valid: true },
       disposable: { valid: true },
       mx: { valid: true },
       smtp: { valid: false, reason: 'Mailbox not found.' }
     },
     reason: 'smtp'
   }
   ```
4. As you can see, Deep Email Validator runs five different checks to ensure the validity of the email address. In this case, the ID is invalid because there is an issue with SMTP. The mailbox is not found. That’s why the valid field is set to false and the reason field is set to smtp. It should not return false.

You can read more about this validation [here](https://www.abstractapi.com/guides/node-email-validation#:%7E:text=Node%20email%20validation.-,How%20Do%20I%20Check%20if%20An%20Email%20is%20Valid%20in,and%20the%20SMTP%20server%20response.)